# Assigning neighbours in array

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to create simple table of fields, that store information about their neighbours. Here's my code:

```
class Field:
    posx = 0
    posy = 0
    used = False
    letter = ''
    neighbours = []

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.posx = x
        self.posy = y

    def addNeighbour(self,neighbour):
        self.neighbours.append(neighbour)

m, n = 2, 2   # size of table
fields=[[0 for y in range(0, n)] for x in range(0, m)]

for i in range(0, m):
    for j in range(0, n):     
        fields[i][j] = Field(i, j)

for i in range(0, m):
    for j in range(0, n):
        for k in range(i-1, i+2):
            for l in range(j-1, j+2):
                if (k in range(0, m) and l in range(0, n)
                                    and (k != i or l != j)):
                    print('{} {}'.format(i, j))
                    fields[i][j].addNeighbour(fields[k][l])
```

It prints out good values, for simple 2x2 table every field(i,j) has 3 neighbours. Problem is, instead of assigning 3 neighbours to each field, it assigns neighbours of all fields to all fields (so each field's neighbours list has 12 elements instead of 3). Could anyone point out what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`neighbours` is a class variable, hence all the `Field` instances add to the same list. Just make it an instance variable:

```
class Field:
    # do NOT put neighbours, posx, posy, letter here!! They are instance variables

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.posx = x
        self.posy = y
        self.neighbours = []
        self.letter = ''
```

Also, a single comprehension will do to create the grid of fields:

```
m, n = 2, 2   # size of table
fields=[[Field(x, y) for y in range(n)] for x in range(m)]
```